# Passing an array of json objects from one powershell workflow to another

Tags: json, powershell, automation, powershell-workflow

I want to pass $output, which is an array of json objects into $json which is an array of json objects in mod3, which is a powershell workflow. I am using this code, but it always results in an error:

```
workflow mod4 {
$output = mod1
mod3 -$json $output}
```

Also $json is used in the inline script in mod3. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: mod3 -json $output ? Including the error would be helpful.

Comment: It would also be good to see the code of mod1 and mod3. My assumption above is that you've declared $json in a param block of mod3.